# Don't show this page anymore (JQUERY cookie)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to implement cookies for my website, i just wanted to redirect users to a splash page and have a "remember me" checkbox there and once they checked off that and pressed enter, they will not see that page anymore.
So using [COOKIE Plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) I can set a cookie for users and redirect them to the page, but I wasn't able to implement how to detect the remember me box..

```
$(function() {
    var COOKIE_NAME = 'splash-page-cookie';
    $go = $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME);
    if ($go == null) {
        $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, 'test', { path: '/', expires: 6 });
        window.location = "/splash.php"
    }
    else {
    }
});
```

Anybody has done like this before? Or anybody have any similar idea to implement this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution #1 (With alert boxes)**: I came up with this but without the COOKIE Plugin. Hopefully you can get some use out of this. Mostly Pure JS with some JQuery to fancy it up a little.

Here is the [DEMO](http://www.totallytotallyamazing.com/jsFiddle/cookie/index.html).

Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#remember').click(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#x').text("You're the Best!");
            setCookie();
        } else {
            $('#x').text("Come on, You know you want to!");
        }
    });
});

function setCookie() {
   user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
   if (user != "" && user != null) {
       addCookie("username", user, 30);
   }
}

function addCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
    //window.location.href = "https://www.google.com"; // redirect after the prompt
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user=getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
        window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
    }
}
function goTo() {
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="checkCookie();">
<h1>Splash Page</h1>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" id="remember"> Remember me
<br>
<input type="button" value="Enter" onClick="goTo();">
</form>
<p><div id='x'></div></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Solution #2 (NO alert boxes)**: I came up with this as a second simplified solution by request which is more compatible with mobile (Chrome, etc.). Hopefully you can get some use out of this. Mostly Pure JS with some JQuery to fancy it up a little.

Here is the [DEMO](http://www.totallytotallyamazing.com/jsFiddle/cookie/indexNoAlert.html).

Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#remember').click(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#x').text("You're the Best!!!");
            addCookie(30);
        } else {
            $('#x').text("Come on, You know you want to!");
            deleteAllCookies();
        }
    });
});

function deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}

function addCookie(exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = expires;
}

function checkCookie() {
    if (document.cookie == false) {
        //alert("Welcome New User");
    } else if (document.cookie.indexOf("expires") >= 0) {
        //alert("Welcome Back");
        window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
    }
}

function goTo() {
        window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="checkCookie();">
<h1>Splash Page</h1>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" id="remember"> Remember me
<br>
<input type="button" value="Enter" onClick="goTo();">
</form>
<p><div id='x'></div></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i was away for a while.. just saw that and this is great, can we get rid of prompting and just set a cookie with default name?

Comment: it doesn't work on Chrome/Android . . but working in all other browsers in desktop and mobile (Chrome, Safari, Opera, FF), do you know what would be the issue?

Comment: @Amir I hope my above second solution works for you. It is good on my end.

Comment: Hey man, i really appreciate it. . one more thing: I want to check if cookie is set, so i can say if cookie is set load the page else redirect to splash page (your code) Can i do it via PHP? or i should do it via JS?

Comment: I don't know how to tag you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917745/check-if-cookie-is-set-then-load-the-page-else-redirect-page?noredirect=1#comment40569891_25917745

Comment: "@username" or for me "@totallytotallyamazing". No quotes though.